# Javascript - second object created is different from first one

Tags: javascript, html, oop, prototype

Got here parent class `Shape` and it's child `Rectangle`.
When I create a few `Rectangle` object problem occures - first one has `draw` function, but the others are not! Also it even has other type (`Object` vs `Shape`)

Why does this happen?

Here is the error
[image]
[image]

And here is the code

`index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title> 

    </head>   
    <body>        
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Rect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Shape.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Shape.js

```
function Shape(center){
    this.center = center;
    this.angle = 0;
}
```

Rect.js

```
var Rectangle = function(center, width,height){
    Shape.call(this, center);
    this.mType = "Rectangle";
    this.mWidth = width;
    this.mHeight = height;

    var prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
    prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
    Rectangle.prototype = prototype;
};

Rectangle.prototype.draw = function () {
 //for the test
    console.log("Rect is drawn");
};
```

Comment: Every time you create a `Rectangle`, you create a new `prototype`. But you only defined `Rectangle.prototype.draw` once.

Comment: @Barmar so I reaches `draw` for the first time it's been created but after it's only calls constructor function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that every time you call the `Rectangle` constructor, you're creating a new `Rectangle.prototype`, which replaces the old one. But you only added the `draw` method to the first `Rectangle.prototype`.

You shouldn't be creating the prototype chain in the constructor, you should set it up once.

```js
function Shape(center){
    this.center = center;
    this.angle = 0;
}

function Rectangle(center, width,height){
    Shape.call(this, center);
    this.mType = "Rectangle";
    this.mWidth = width;
    this.mHeight = height;
};

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);

Rectangle.prototype.draw = function () {
 //for the test
    console.log("Rect is drawn");
};

Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var up = new Rectangle(1, 1, 3);
var down = new Rectangle(2, 1, 3);

up.draw();
down.draw();
console.log(Shape.prototype.isPrototypeOf(up));
console.log(down instanceof Shape);
```

See the examples at [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Thank you

Comment: But, when we try `up.isPrototypeOf(Shape);` (or) `down.isPrototypeOf(Shape);` it still says `false`. Why?

Comment: I think it should be `Shape.isPrototypeOf(up)`

Comment: Or `Shape.prototype.isPrototypeOf(up)`

Comment: See the example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf

Comment: Ah.. You nailed it Barmar!.. One more reason why I was not getting it that the `Shape.js` inclusion should go up before `Rect.js`

Comment: @Barmar oh, btw, a time ago it inheritance was something like `function Rectangle(center, width,height){ .... this.prototype = Shape;}`

Comment: @Barmar is there some pros from using `var prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
    prototype.constructor = Rectangle;
    Rectangle.prototype = prototype;`

Comment: @DanilGholtsman That works as long as you just need to inherit the parent prototype, not add new methods to the child's prototype.

Comment: @Barmar on my previous job where I got a lot of JS we always was avoid of `Object.create` because of `IE7` was not supporting it, and that kinds of inheritance was working fine, AFAIR

Comment: @Barmar is there some article about different approeaches cons and pros and what is better to use today?

Comment: @DanilGholtsman No one cares about IE7 any more. IE8 is about as old as anyone bothers with, and that's becoming less important.

Comment: @DanilGholtsman It's just personal style whether you create a new variable first. It makes no practical difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137640/discussion-between-danil-gholtsman-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to remove (or) comment the `Rectangle.prototype = prototype;` statement in your `Rect.js` file where you do a 'reverse' of the previous line.

**Rect.js**

```
var Rectangle = function(center, width,height){
    Shape.call(this, center);
    this.mType = "Rectangle";
    this.mWidth = width;
    this.mHeight = height;

    var prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
    prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

    // Comment the below line, to make your code work.
    //Rectangle.prototype = prototype;
};
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: How does he get `Rect` to inherit from `Shape` if he does this?

Comment: Hi Barmar, My answer is more towards eliminating the error

Comment: And with your answer (or) my way of commenting out that `Rectangle.prototype...` line, when we try `up.isPrototypeOf(Shape);` (or) `down.isPrototypeOf(Shape);` it still says false.

Comment: @DavidR hmm, yeah thats interesting